# How do I get row from django database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello I am trying to create a clockIn clockOut website and I do not know how to get a row filtered by a persons name to add in the clock out time.

Here is the code. The first if statement is working fine but the else statement is where I am having trouble doing:

```
        if response.POST.get("clockIn"):
            if form.is_valid():
                n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
                t = Name(name = n, timeIn=datetime.now(), timeOut=NULL)
                t.save()
        else:
            if form.is_valid():
                n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
                t = Name.objects
                t = t.filter(name = n)
                s = t(timeOut = datetime.now()) 
                s.save()
```

Here is my models.py:

```
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    timeIn = models.DateTimeField()
    timeOut = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: btw when I try to refresh my website it says 'QuerySet' object is not callable.

Comment: `s = t(timeOut = datetime.now()) ` this is wrong. This is not the way to perform updates on specific field. This line throws QuerySet object is not callable.

Comment: @MahenderThakur what do I need to change it to?

Comment: Check the answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if form.is_valid():
    n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
    # If there are unique entries for this name then you should use get method instead of filter
    try:
        t = Name.objects.get(name=n)
        t.timeOut = datetime.now()
        t.save()
    except Exception as _: # or maybe NameDoesNotExist exception
        # Handle case
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give enough information to solve this issue properly . Where is your `models.py` file ? You should add `models.py` file with your question .

By the way , in Django, to get a row using filter is as like as below :

```
name=your_person_name
Entry.objects.filter(person_name=name)
```

Comment: I have added the models.py file